# How to test routes using mocha

Tags: testing, routes, mocha.js

I am creating a MERN app and have routes defined. For the sake of simplicity say I have a User model and users routes for registering, logging in, and deleting a user. How do I test these routes using mocha. Currently, I am testing my model using mocha like this

```
module.exports = registerUsers = () => {
  describe('Validating records', () => {
    it('should register users', (done) => {
      users.forEach((user) => {
        User.create(user).then(() => {
          assert(!user.isNew);
        });
      });

      done();
    });

    it('requires a username', (done) => {
      const user = new User({
        username: undefined,
        email: 'user@gmail.com',
        securityQuestion: 'What is your favorite color?',
        securityAnswer: 'red',
        password: 'password',
      });

      const validationResult = user.validateSync();
      const { message } = validationResult.errors.username;

      assert(message === 'Path `username` is required.');

      done();
    });
  });
};
```

However, I am at a complete loss with how to do this with testing routes. It might be kinda dumb but I might need an example of some code and detailed instructions on how to get it up and running.

I see from Mocha documentation the following...

```
  describe('GET /api/users', function() {
    it('respond with an array of users', function() {
      // ...
    });
  });
});

describe('app', function() {
  describe('GET /users', function() {
    it('respond with an array of users', function() {
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

but I am just at a loss with what to do with it and how it even connects with the app. I'm guessing I would have to do something with my package.json but I'm not really sure.

Comment: You mean the endpoints on the express backend? Try something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.